# Call Oracle Stored Procedure from PHP with input and output Parameters

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Im trying to implement an easy Stored Procedure into PHP.
Im using Oracle SQL and I have to use PDO for connection to the database.

The Procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE RABATTPROZEDUR 
(
  VAR_KUNDE IN NUMBER  
, VAR_RABATT IN NUMBER  
, VAR_DATUM IN DATE  
, ERGEBNIS OUT NUMBER  
) AS 
var_volumenBegin NUMBER := 0;
var_volumenEnd NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN


Select SUM(TOTALPRICE) into var_volumenBegin From Orderposition Where Ordid IN (Select Ordid From Orders Where Custid = var_kunde);

Update Orderposition Set TOTALPRICE = (TOTALPRICE * (100 - var_rabatt) / 100) Where Ordid IN(Select Ordid From Orders Where Custid = var_kunde And Orderdate >= var_datum);

Select SUM(TOTALPRICE) into var_volumenEnd From Orderposition Where Ordid IN (Select Ordid From Orders Where Custid = var_kunde); 

ergebnis := var_volumenBegin-var_volumenEnd;

END RABATTPROZEDUR;
```

In PHP, it looks like this:

```
$ergebnis = 0;
                    $a= ':cid';
                    $b= ':percent';

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL rabattprozedur(:var_kunde,:var_rabatt,to_date(':var_datum'),:ergebnis)");
                    $stmt->bindParam(':var_kunde',$a,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':var_rabatt',$b,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':var_datum',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':ergebnis',$ergebnis,PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

                    //$stmt->bindParam($a = ':cid',$b = ':percent',$date,$ergebnis); 
                    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    $stmt->execute();
```

Unfortunately that doesnt work. The error message im getting is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1722 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01722: invalid number (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)
```

I tried different methods and approaches but cant get it to work.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you make sure with the date format?

Comment: use date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); instead of $date

Comment: @ujash joshi: thanks for the quick answer, but it's still not working and i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

- $a and $b need to be actual values
- you need to remove the quotes around the date in the SQL statement
- PDO needs a size set for the out bound bind variable

With this SQL:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RABATTPROZEDUR 
(
    VAR_KUNDE IN NUMBER  
    , VAR_RABATT IN NUMBER  
    , VAR_DATUM IN DATE  
    , ERGEBNIS OUT NUMBER  
) AS 
BEGIN
  ERGEBNIS := VAR_KUNDE - (VAR_RABATT * VAR_KUNDE / 100);
END RABATTPROZEDUR;
/
```

You can use:

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/orcl', 'cj', 'cj');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$ergebnis = 0;

// $a and $b must be the PHP data values
$a = 100;
$b = 1;

$date = '17-JAN-2017';

// Remove quotes around :var_datum
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL rabattprozedur(:var_kunde,:var_rabatt,to_date(:var_datum),:ergebnis)");
$stmt->bindParam(':var_kunde',$a,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':var_rabatt',$b,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':var_datum',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
// Set a length for the outbind
$stmt->bindParam(':ergebnis',$ergebnis,PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 40);
$stmt->debugDumpParams();
$stmt->execute();

echo "Output param is: $ergebnis\n";
```